# Jquery : On clicking the button select drop down option

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am jquery learner.

```
<select multiple id="update-select" data-type="test1, test2">
        <option value="3">test1</option>
        <option value="4">test2</option>
        <option value="5">test3 test</option>
        <option value="5">test test</option>
</select>

<input type="button" id ="btn" value ="click me">


$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#btn").click(function(){

   });   
});
```

[jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/V85Vx/17/)

I am setting the data-type value dynamically based on some server data.
on clicking the button option whose value equal to data-type value must be selected

Here data-type values are `test1` and `test2` so option `test1`, and `test2` must be selected on clicking the button

Note: data-type values can have two word values like test test, option text also 
can have test test

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#btn").on('click', function(){
       $('#update-select option').prop('selected', false);
       $.each($('#update-select').data('type').split(','), function(i, opt) {
           $('#update-select option:contains('+ $.trim(opt) +')').prop('selected', true);
       });
   });   
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/V85Vx/20/)

Comment: not sure if .prop will be supported in older versions of IE. in case this dosen't work in IE, you can use attr instead. so everything will remain the same except in last line .prop will be replaced by .attr.

Comment: `.prop` has nothing to do with IE, it's jQuery, and as such works for the browsers supported by the jQuery version used.

Comment: and **do not** use `attr()` for properties, that's what `prop()` is for.

Comment: A doubt, we shall give most priority for `prop()` while setting properties, But is there any ill effects on using `attr()` at that place.?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy - yes there are ill effects. The `attr()` method only changes the attribute, and not the underlying property used by many jQuery methods, so if you change the `selected` attribute with `attr()`, and then check it with something like `.is(':selected')`, you'll get the wrong value back as the property was not changed, only the attribute was, and this will give you a shitload of problems in the long run.

Comment: @adeneo If only I'd seen your comments a week ago.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btn").click(function(){
         $('#update-select option').prop('selected', false);
        var select = $("#update-select").attr('data-type').split(',');
        for(var i=0; i<select.length; i++){
           $('#update-select option:contains('+ $.trim(select[i]) +')').prop('selected', true);   
        }
    });   
});
```

check http://jsfiddle.net/alaminopu/V85Vx/23/

Answer (score 1):

Use [.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) function to get your target `option` tags and select it afterwards.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#btn").click(function(){  

       var xText =$('#update-select').data('type');

       $('#update-select option').filter(function(){
           return xText.indexOf($(this).text()) != -1;   
       }).prop('selected', true);

   });   
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/V85Vx/22/)